# How to move character forward and also face moving direction?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touchscreen

[image]I am a newbie to Unity, any help will be much appreciated.

I want to make a game where character (shown in below image) moves forward continuously. Character has to move upwards when user touches mobile screen (long touch will make character move upwards continuously), otherwise character falls down slowly due to gravity. Main theme is to avoid touching obstacles and character motion should be curvy. This is a 3D game, but character moves in x,y axis.

Till now, I have written below code to move the character forward and also move character upward when mobile screen touched, but it didn't worked as expected.

In update method:

```
transform.position += Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed;
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    if (Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        // move player against the gravity
        transform.position += Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed;
    }
    if (Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        // gravity acts on the character, so character falls down
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work as expected, so what did it do? Just nothing or some other behavior?

Comment: Are you using `rigidbody` or `character controller` on your character?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look into one of the Quaternion functions - LookRotation:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html

The code should be as simple as this:

```
Vector3 relativePos = target.position - transform.position;
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos);
transform.rotation = rotation;
```

where `target.position` is the position where you touch the screen, `transform.position` is the position and `transform.rotation`is the rotation of your moving object.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is a great piece of code, thanks. My characters now look at whatever I choose by replacing 'target.position' with the position of they should be looking at.