# How to make character face direction of travel?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, bezier

Does anyone know how I could adapt my code so that the character faces the direction it travels in? I realise this question may seem a duplicate to existing questions but I'm not sure where/how to apply the correct rotation code in my code :

```
coroutineAllowed = false;
Vector2 p0 = routelist[routeIndex].routes[routeNumber].GetChild(0).position;
Vector2 p1 = routelist[routeIndex].routes[routeNumber].GetChild(1).position;
Vector2 p2 = routelist[routeIndex].routes[routeNumber].GetChild(2).position;
Vector2 p3 = routelist[routeIndex].routes[routeNumber].GetChild(3).position;

while (tParam < 1)
{
    tParam += Time.deltaTime * speedModifier;
    characterPosition = Mathf.Pow(1 - tParam, 3) * p0 +
        3 * Mathf.Pow(1 - tParam, 2) * tParam * p1 +
        3 * (1 - tParam) * Mathf.Pow(tParam, 2) * p2 +
        Mathf.Pow(tParam, 3) * p3;
    transform.position = characterPosition;
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move character forward and also face moving direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39141184/how-to-move-character-forward-and-also-face-moving-direction)

Comment: I've tried the solutions like the one you linked but can't seem to get them working in my code :(

Comment: For  a 2D or 3D app?

Comment: @derHugo Sorry for not clarifying, it's a 2D app :)

Comment: If you select the character gameobject, what axis is pointing in the direction he's "facing" (red arrow=x, green arrow=y, blue arrow=z)?  also do you want the player to face exactly the direction they are moving or only exactly left or right depending on which is most like the direction they are moving?

Comment: @Ruzihm he's facing the same way as the blue arrow :) I'd like the player to face exactly the way he's travelling... Also, I only get the arrows when I untoggle 2D... it's actually a 2D game if that helps to know?

Comment: @Lloyd What color arrow is coming out of the top of the character's head (pointing towards the camera) when you look at it in 3D mode? This question would be a lot easier to answer if you included a screenshot of the character's gameobject being selected in scene view so that the local axes are visible

Comment: The problem why a simply `LookAt` doesn't work is that it appears that your object is a 2D sprite ... so when you make its forawrd vector LookAt a position in the same 2D plane it "disappears" because now it is 90° rotated and you look onto its edge ... Couldn't you simply use `transform.up = direction;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Sprites in Unity are (usually if not always) normal to their local `forward` direction. This is why setting their local forward to be orthogonal to the direction of an orthographic camera tends to turn them invisible.

From the images you've shared in other answers, it seems like you need to rotate the character's local "up" direction in the opposite direction they are moving, while keeping the character's local "forward" direction pointing in the global forward direction.

You can use [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) to do this although you'll need to be a little creative with the parameters, giving the direction you want to face away from as the `up` parameter, and global `forward` as the forward parameter.

```
coroutineAllowed = false;
Vector2 p0 = routelist[routeIndex].routes[routeNumber].GetChild(0).position;
Vector2 p1 = routelist[routeIndex].routes[routeNumber].GetChild(1).position;
Vector2 p2 = routelist[routeIndex].routes[routeNumber].GetChild(2).position;
Vector2 p3 = routelist[routeIndex].routes[routeNumber].GetChild(3).position;

while (tParam < 1)
{
    tParam += Time.deltaTime * speedModifier;
    Vector3 fromPosition = transform.position;

    characterPosition = Mathf.Pow(1 - tParam, 3) * p0 +
        3 * Mathf.Pow(1 - tParam, 2) * tParam * p1 +
        3 * (1 - tParam) * Mathf.Pow(tParam, 2) * p2 +
        Mathf.Pow(tParam, 3) * p3;
    transform.position = characterPosition;

    Vector3 newLocalUpDirection = fromPosition - transform.position;

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, newLocalUpDirection);

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you solved it! Works a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform.LookAt(Vector3)` like this:

```
characterPosition = Mathf.Pow(1 - tParam, 3) * p0 +
    3 * Mathf.Pow(1 - tParam, 2) * tParam * p1 +
    3 * (1 - tParam) * Mathf.Pow(tParam, 2) * p2 +
    Mathf.Pow(tParam, 3) * p3;
transform.LookAt(characterPosition);
transform.position = characterPosition;
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I added your code but my character disappears from the scene? When I click play he's nowhere to be seen?

Comment: @Lloyd it's your code with a single line addition of LookAt, which should only change the rotation. If your code works for moving, this shouldnt affect it. What's happening in the hierarchy to your player?

Comment: @Mikedg added the single line of code (the LookAt) and the character disappears. He's still active under the hierarchy and I can see his rotation changes under the inspector.... have you got any ideas?

Comment: is it possible he's just facing away from the camera and isn't viewable from behind? if the player was 2d or weirdly structured 3d that would be possible.

Comment: @Mikedg Ah right ok..... the player is a 2D model... I'm new to all this so don't really know what to do next :/

Comment: @Lloyd that might be it then. In your scene view, try moving your scene view around the player and see if he becomes visible in the scene view. If he does, then that's the problen and we probably need some more context about your game to figure eout the real solution. The easy way to rotate around is to double click your player in the game hierarchy. That should select him, center him, and zoom in, in your scene view. Then hold the alt/option + left mouse and drag around to rotate your scene camera around that game object.

Comment: @Mikedg Thank you. I did what you said and he did in fact become visible again! Although when I clicked Play then immediately selected the Scene tab, only  his animation would work. I could see from the inspector that his position would stay fixed. If I just left it on the Game scene, I could see that his position and rotation would change although I wouldn't be able to see him! :( do you know how I could resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it that way, get the `Lookvector` first, then direct the character to look into it.

```
while (tParam < 1)
{
    tParam += Time.deltaTime * speedModifier;
    characterPosition = Mathf.Pow(1 - tParam, 3) * p0 +
        3 * Mathf.Pow(1 - tParam, 2) * tParam * p1 +
        3 * (1 - tParam) * Mathf.Pow(tParam, 2) * p2 +
        Mathf.Pow(tParam, 3) * p3;
    Vector3 v3 = characterPosition;
    Vector3 Lookvector = v3 - transform.position;
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Lookvector);
    transform.rotation = rotation;
    transform.position = characterPosition;
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I get an error on the Vector3 Lookvector line though.... it says Operator '-' is ambigious on operands of type 'Vector2' and 'Vector3'...?

Comment: Thanks but it says 'Vector2' does not contain a definition for 'Vector3'?

Comment: How about now ?

Comment: That worked but the character can't be seen :/ I can only see him when switching to Scene view, un-toggling 2D and rotating the view... it's as if I'm looking straight down on him which is why I can't see him maybe?

Comment: The added part only changes direction, try to test it without it to see if you can see the character.

Comment: Maybe you remove the character out of the camera scoop.

Comment: Sorry, which part should I exclude to test?

Comment: Vector3 v3 = characterPosition;
    Vector3 Lookvector = v3 - transform.position;
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Lookvector);
    transform.rotation = rotation;

Comment: Yes I can see the character when I take those lines out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199809/discussion-between-abdelaziz-abdellatef-and-lloyd).

Answer (score -2):

Have you had a look at this:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html

this might also rotate in x and z space, but you can work around this and do something like:

```
// Direction vector
Vector3 relativePos = target.position - transform.position;

// the second argument, upwards, defaults to Vector3.up
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);

// fix rota so that only y rotation occures.
var vectorRota = rotation.EulerAngles;
Vector3 fixedYRotation =  new Vector(0f, vectorRota.y, 0f);

// create Quaternion back from Vector3
Quaternion finalRotation = Quaternion.Euler(fixedYRotation );

// assing rotation to GameObject
gameObject.transform.rotation = finalRotation;
```

Comment: Have you tried your code? Since the LookRotation makes the object align it's Z axis with the direction, I doubt resetting all rotation axis except Z would be enough to fix this.